# How to change array format from one multidimensional form to another?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array in the below format. What I try to do I am getting either undefined offset error or repeated array cells.

```
arr[] = Array
            (
            [0] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = A
                   [grp2]=Array(
                        [0] => a
                        [1] => b
                        [2] => c

                    )
              )
           [1] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = B
                   [grp2]=Array(
                        [0] => d
                        [1] => e

                    )
                  )
              )
```

I want to convert the above array to the following format.

```
arr[] = Array
            (
            [0] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = A
                   [grp2]=a

                    )

           [1] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = A
                   [grp2]=b

                    )

             [2] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = A
                   [grp2]=c

                    )

           [3] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = B
                   [grp2]=d

                    )
          [4] => Array
                    (
                   [grp1] = B
                   [grp2]=e

                    )
           )
```

*First of all sorry that my question is not explained well. Actually I dont know what to ask in this case. Any edits will be appreciated.*

Comment: This is very simple. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why don't you just build a new one off this one. All you would have to do is access the deepest part of the arrays, since the grp 1 values of A or B are parents(not really parents but like group titles) of grp 2

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen : What I tried was I used a foreach statement for the subarray [grp2] and inserted the grp[1] values into each one. But its not working.

Comment: @Charles : Could you provide an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally do not give out complete answers to simple stuff like this, but I do not have much else to do at the moment. Instead of explaining the code, in prose, I have just commented all the statements:

```
// Create a new array to hold the modified values
$newArr = array();

// Go over each item
foreach ($arr as $item) {

    // Grab the uppercase letter
    $uppercaseLetter = $item['grp1'];

    // Go over the lowercase letters
    foreach ($item['grp2'] as $lowercaseLetter) {

        // Combine the uppercase and lowercase letters
        // into a new array
        $newArr[] = array(
            'grp1' => $uppercaseLetter,
            'grp2' => $lowercaseLetter,
        );
    }
}
// Show the new array
var_dump($newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
foreach($arr as $v){
    foreach($v['grp2'] as $val){
        $array[] = array('grp1' => $v['grp1'], 'grp2' => $val);
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$temp = array();
$i= 0;        
foreach($arr as $key=>$value){

foreach($value["grp2"] as $key2=>$value2){
$temp[$i]["grp1"] = $value["grp1"];
$temp[$i]["grp2"] = $value2;
++$i;

}

}

print_r ($temp);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [grp1] => A [grp2] => a ) 
[1] => Array ( [grp1] => A [grp2] => b ) 
[2] => Array ( [grp1] => A [grp2] => c ) 
[3] => Array ( [grp1] => B [grp2] => d ) 
[4] => Array ( [grp1] => B [grp2] => e ) )
```